# How to make side bar active?

Tags: laravel

In below code role row is active but while i click in roles create inside roles page which is not mentioned in the sidebar the column is inactive
image for the create page is https://prnt.sc/qhspxs
image for the index page is https://prnt.sc/qhsq5o

```
<li class="treeview {{Request::is('admin/administration/*') ? 'active':''}}" >
          <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i> <span>Administration</span>
            <span class="pull-right-container">
              <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
            </span>
          </a>
          <ul class="treeview-menu">
            <li class="{{'admin/administration/roles' == request()->path() ? 'active' : ''}}"><a href="{{ route('roles.index') }}"><i class="fa fa-users"></i> Roles</a></li>
            <li class="{{'admin/administration/users' == request()->path() ? 'active' : ''}}"><a href="{{ route('users.index') }}"><i class="fa fa-users"></i> Users</a></li>
            <li class="{{'admin/administration/company' == request()->path() ? 'active' : ''}}"><a href="{{ route('company.index') }}"><i class="fa fa-users"></i> Companies</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check if request path is in array of possible routes
Try following code

```
<li class="treeview {{Request::is('admin/administration/*') ? 'active':''}}" >
    <a href="#">
    <i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i> <span>Administration</span>
    <span class="pull-right-container">
        <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
    </span>
    </a>
    <ul class="treeview-menu">
    <li class="{{in_array(request()->path(),['admin/administration/roles','admin/administration/roles/create','admin/administration/roles/edit']) ? 'active' : ''}}"><a href="{{ route('roles.index') }}"><i class="fa fa-users"></i> Roles</a></li>
    <li class="{{'admin/administration/users' == request()->path() ? 'active' : ''}}"><a href="{{ route('users.index') }}"><i class="fa fa-users"></i> Users</a></li>
    <li class="{{'admin/administration/company' == request()->path() ? 'active' : ''}}"><a href="{{ route('company.index') }}"><i class="fa fa-users"></i> Companies</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the current route and check if it is equal to the Selected Option:

```
<li>
    <a href="#">Administration</a>
    <ul style="<?php if (Request::is('administration/*')) echo "display:block"; ?>">
    <li class ="{{ Route::currentRouteNamed('administration.index') ? 'active' : '' }}">
         <a href="{{ route('administration.index')}}">> View Tasks</a>
    </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```